# Selenium Action chains doubble click instead of single click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using actionchains to click multiple buttons on a page. But what i have written preforms a doubble click instead of a single click:

```
y_off = 143
ed.move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(x_off, y_off).click().perform()
time.sleep(1)
y_off_2 = 265
ed.move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(x_off, y_off_2).click().perform()
time.sleep(1)
y_off_3 = 387
ed.move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(x_off, y_off_3).click().perform()
time.sleep(1)
y_off_4 = 509
ed.move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(x_off, y_off_4).click().perform()
```

Comment: Can you share all your code to let us debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discorvered the solution.
I removed the .perform() argument in all lines and wrote ed.perform() as the last line.
Aparently it is because there is a hidden .build() in all .perform(), so every time it was executing the line above aswell.